# Unity C# System.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.diagnostics

I am new to this and to programming. I have started a Unity course on Udemy and very much enjoying it.

Apologise if this has been asked before but:

When I save my code on visual studio, a using statement is automatically added.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

How do i stop this from adding its-self every time? it always stops my code running in Unity and i scratch my head each time trying to figure out what I have done wrong!

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: well does any of your code have that dependency? what flavor of visual studio?

Comment: Probably a visual studio extension does that.

Comment: I'm using VS19. There's nothing in my code that uses it. It just seems to add it's self when I save the code before going into Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `Visual Studio Code`.
It's super light and supports so many powerful extensions for C# programming, Debugging, Shader Programming, ...